# Jenkins job matrix slaves delay

Tags: jenkins

I have a job matrix with three slaves, slave1, slave2, slave3.

Is it possible start a build with some delay from one slave to another? So first start slave1, so slave2 after 10 seconds for example and finally slave3.

Then only option found is "Run each configuration sequentially", but this is not what I need.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can try "Quiet Period" in job configuration under general section "General >> Advanced..." Once you check this option and provide time (in seconds), your job will wait for specified time before run.

[image: Jenkins job quiet period]

Comment: That option is to delay two different builds, not builds from slaves into the same build, that is my goal.